# Addressing Me.Products in an SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

How do I handle ***Me.Products***?  I am using Northwind.mdf database in table "Products". The table was drug onto a dbml file.

***Me.Products*** needs to be defined with a statement or a file to make it usable.  Maybe the dim statement is incorrect?

```
Partial Public Class NorthwindDataContext
    Dim Products As Object
    Public Function GetProductsByCategory(ByVal id1 As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of Product)
        Return From p In Me.Products _
               Where p.ProductID = id1 _
               Select p
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very weak in VB but still try it
yes dim is used to create variables. First create an object of northwinddatacontext for eg.

```
dim db as new northwinddatacontext()
```

then you can get the table as

```
var query = from p in db.Products 
            where p.ProductID = id 
            select p
```

Comment: It is northwinddatacontext. How can you dim it?  It is a class statement for reference!  How do I add the reference to northwind database without using northwinddatacontext.

Comment: @user1228044 you are using linq2sql and you drag the Products table to dbml file, so whenever we add tables to dbml file, datacontext is created