# How do I write a class statement for a database

Tags: asp.net, database, linq, linq-to-sql

In vb:

```
db = New DBDataContext(c:\path\db.mdf)
```

How do I write a class statement to declare DBDataContext:

```
Class DBDataContext
     **what code goes here**
End Class
```

I have made a dbml file in LINQ-SQL for Table1.  Can someone give me hints that I can go by to produce this Class statement.

Comment: If you made a dbml file a context class is already generated.

Comment: As was told before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550097/addressing-me-products-in-an-sql-database#comment15282016_11550190. Seen your other questions I think you better read some linq-to-sql manual to get the basics first and then come back and ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an example like this in VB:

```
Using db = New DbDataContext()
    Try
        db.Connection.Open()
        db.Transaction = db.Connection.BeginTransaction()

        Using command = db.Connection.CreateCommand()
            command.Transaction = db.Transaction
            command.CommandText = File.ReadAllText("/path/to/file.sql")
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        db.Transaction.Commit()
    Catch e As Exception
        db.Transaction.Rollback()
        Throw e
    Finally
        db.Connection.Close()
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: I would not even know where to start with code like that. What is body-multiline lambda?